# HLOOKUP to copy colour and formatting of a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet which summarises data from another page (within the same workbook) using a drop down selection and HLOOKUP to bring up the required cells. 
I need the cells to also copy across the formatting as they are colour coded red and green to signify completion. 
I realise V/HLookup only copies across the content and not formatting and was wondering whether it is possible to achieve this with VBA?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is only possible with VBA, yes.

Answer (score 0):

After you get what you want with `HLOOKUP` you can paste it on your desired cell or cell range with

```
Worksheets("name").Cells(x, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Worksheets("name").Cells(x, x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```